# Select multiple checkbox with same name

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, checkbox

For example I have 5 checkboxes and all of them have same name. I check checkboxes, submit and then delete checkboxes I checked. Here I don´t have any problems, the problem it´s check for example the number 1 , 3 , 5 , etc , but has the same name and when check one uncheck other

How it´s possible check all checbox i want from for example 5 checboxes

For example :

```
Check 1 - checked
Check 2 - unchecked
Check 3 - checked
Check 4 - unchecked
Check 5 - checked
```

Thank´s Regards

Comment: Set up a fiddle for this. Ans post what you've tried.

Comment: `and i want - for delete i check - send and delete the checkboxes i check , for this i haven´t problem` Can you elaborate? please.

Answer (score 4):

If you **really** can't give them different names or id and you want to check them all :

```
$('input[name="thename"]').prop('checked', true);
```

If you want to check the first, the third and the fifth checkbox, you can do this :

```
$('input[name="thename"]').filter(':eq(0), :eq(2), :eq(4)').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: I'm not sure about what OP wants. Maybe this answer will disappear next time I re-re-reread the question.

Comment: The question it´s easy , you have 5 checkbox with same name how i can do multiple select for example check 1 , 3 and 3 , if have the same name i can´t but it´s possible check multiple checkbox with the same name ..... ?

Comment: How do you decide what checkboxes to check ?

Answer (score 2):

use id's to identify them individually:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='name' id='cb_1'/>
<input type='checkbox' name='name' id='cb_2'/>
<input type='checkbox' name='name' id='cb_3'/>
<input type='checkbox' name='name' id='cb_4'/>
<input type='checkbox' name='name' id='cb_5'/>
```

Comment: Yes but the problem it´s how i can select and unselect from for example 5 checkbox , the question it´s what i need for can check or uncheck from 5 for example 3 if have the same name

Comment: @Fran, I just told you how to, don't be scared to do a bit of research, I gave you all that you needed for this question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete checkbox you check then this could help if you use jQuery

```
1 <input type='checkbox' name='my_name' /><br>
2 <input type='checkbox' name='my_name' /><br>
3 <input type='checkbox' name='my_name' /><br>
4 <input type='checkbox' name='my_name' /><br>
5 <input type='checkbox' name='my_name' /><br>
    <script type="text/javascript">​
        // Event handler activates when value of input with specified name is changed
        $("input[name=my_name]").on("change", function(event) {
            // checks if checkbox was checked, if so - deletes it
            if (true === $(this).prop('checked')) $(this).remove();
        });​
    </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/56nBw/1/

Comment: Ahahaha... this would help a little if you used ajax :D